# How to include a gridview in another activity android

Tags: android, gridview

I want to show **SOME** of the uploaded pictures by users in the gridviews shown below and by clicking on "See All" users can go to a new activity where all their uploaded pictures will be in a gridview (like a gallery)  . I tried building a different activity(suppose activity_1) where all the pictures load in a gridview and then tried to  that activity in the user's profile activity(activity_2) but they dont show up. I think it's because activity_1 doesn't start so the adapters don't work. How do I solve this and is there any other way to achieve this ??

[User's Profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9E10Q.png)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you should use fragments to change them dynamically between activities?